# Cannot open SVGZ File in Firefox, Safari, IE

Tags: html, svg, svgz

I have a `SVGZ` file which will not open in Firefox, Safari and IE. Does anyone know why the `SVGZ` file won't open in any of those browsers?

Comment: This link might help you please try it 

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24797/when-should-i-use-svg-or-svgz-for-my-web-graphics

Comment: @James: Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311533/is-svgz-really-worth-a-dedicated-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at this thread:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24797/when-should-i-use-svg-or-svgz-for-my-web-graphics

Sounds like you might have a server config problem. From user horatio:

> Support for compressed svg will vary by browser, but you need to configure the server to properly flag the svgz file with information about its encoding to explicitly tell the browser how to decode it upon receipt.
>
> Server response for svgz needs to be configured to include "Content-encoding: gzip"

Comment: i had configure Content-encoding: gzip in **IIS HTTP Response Headers** but didn't work.

Comment: This solution is not helpful for opening a file on your local filesystem. Is there any way to do this without starting a local webserver, something not every user may want to (or be able to) do?